# Google Cloud Endpoints API-call ServiceException

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have deployed a Cloud Endpoints API to GAE. Everything looks fine, all methods are listed in the API explorer. However, when I try to call any method, I get a 503 error. The following exception is being thrown:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.ServiceException: Two or more Endpoint classes are mapped to the same service name (MyApiClass): MyApiClass MyApiClass
```

Any suggestions to make it work?

Comment: Can you include the contents of your `web.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: My API file wasn't inside a package, it was directly in src/main/java. Somehow, the error disappeard after I put it in a package.